# holistic/natural data model - where to find?

Tags: database, schema, metamodel, conceptual-model

How or where do I find a holistic or natural data model?

Wikipedia or other/'real' encyclopedias define terms and by doing so relate them to each other (implicitely). In contrast when I create a datamodel for a specific business use case I usually simplify things, which turn on me later as new requirements roll in. I guess, a model that builds on relatively sustainable encyclopedia-definitions becomes in itself relatively sustainable. Scaling a software to that would just hide or unhide parts of the holistic or natural data model as needed. So how would I find such model?

Btw. g00gling 'holistic data model' and 'natural data model' and 'wiki data model' and the like only returned useless non-answers.

My assumption is, since I am usually not the first with very obvious ideas that such thing is called differently and searching for wrong names returns nonsense. So how is it called?

Comment: Such a (kind of generic) model, often called "reference model", would cover a specific problem domain. So, you'd need to include keywords for the problem domain of your business use case in your google query.

Comment: @Gerd Wagner - domain specific models usually do not fit well to each other -> as result you get all sort of nasty interface issues - I think a 'more natural model' would address that issue - response volatility here indicates that I am really the first with that kind of idea - strange...

Comment: What exactly is your idea? A 'more natural model' sounds like a phantom.

Comment: @Gerd Wagner - what I described in the question post seems to be just my idea - I really wonder if and why nobody ever thought about to build a holistic meta model based on an existing 'definition library' such as wikipedia - for me that's so obvious and yet it feels like I am the only one on the planet looking into that

Comment: "a holistic meta model based on an existing 'definition library' such as wikipedia" is a phantom that nobody has seen yet. That's why you don't get any answers. Better don't look for phantoms on SO!

Comment: @Gerd Wagner - ok thanks. Yes, of cause I would not ask for confirmed phantoms. At the moment my brain just dumps me with questions around WHY has nobody seen that - however I 'll stay disciplined to not carry that out here at SO - again thank you for your patience.